# Need help assigning parameters to my definitions

Tags: python-3.4

My code works if I comment out my definitions but I need it to work with the definitions. I don't know which parameters I should assign to them to make the code work properly.

```
#def main():
phrase = input("Enter a phrase: ")
count = {}
print("Number of characters: ",len(phrase))
#def wordCount():
words = phrase.split()
wordCount = len(words)
print("Number of words: ",wordCount)
#def average():
avg = len(phrase)/wordCount
print("The average word length: %.01f" % avg)

#def freqWords():
freqLetter = phrase[0]
max = phrase.count(phrase[0])
for char in phrase:
if char is not " ":
    if phrase.count(char) > max:
        freqLetter = char
        max = phrase.count(char)

print("The most frequent letter: ", freqLetter)

#main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either make phrase, count, etc. as global variable or make them parameters in this case, here is how to do with passing parameters:

```
def main():
    phrase = input("Enter a phrase: ")
    print("Number of characters: ",len(phrase))
    count = wordCount(phrase)
    average(phrase,count)
    freqWords(phrase)

def wordCount(phrase):
    words = phrase.split()
    wordCount = len(words)
    print("Number of words: ",wordCount)
    return wordCount

def average(phrase, wordCount):
    avg = len(phrase)/wordCount
    print("The average word length: %.01f" % avg)

def freqWords(phrase):
    freqLetter = phrase[0]
    max = phrase.count(phrase[0])
    for char in phrase:
        if char is not " ":
            if phrase.count(char) > max:
                freqLetter = char
                max = phrase.count(char)

    print("The most frequent letter: ", freqLetter)

main()
```